# running a registry file on to remote server

Tags: registry

for running it in local system , i use
REGEDIT.EXE   /S "test.reg"

how to run a registry file to remote registry.

by the same command or  by any other means, let me know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use psexec to get a remote command prompt to execute the reg script:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx